# First Windows Store Application

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

I have am writing my first Windows Store Application.  I have some questions / advice not about the software itself but the process of submitting an application to the Windows Store.  Would that be an appropriate question on this site?

Comment: related: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Questions about specific products and services (such as the Windows Store) should go toward whatever support channels that product or service has.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Not arguing.  But to me there are lots of questions that have support channels.   You are a moderator so will go with that.

Comment: @Paparazzi People ask a *lot* of off-topic questions on this site. A common mistake is still a mistake.